# Recursively defined set subset proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, recursion

> Consider the subset $S$ of the set of integers recursively defined by
>
> BASIS STEP: $3 \in S$.
>
> RECURSIVE STEP: If $x \in S$ and $y \in S$, then $x+y \in S$.

**Q:** Show that the set $S$ is the set of all positive integers that are multiples of $3$.

This is an example from Rosen's *Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications*. It first proves that $A$, the set of all positive integers divisible by $3$, is a subset of $S$. I understand this part.

Then $S \subseteq A$ proof is given as the following:

> To prove that $S$ is a subset of $A$, we use the recursive definition
>   of $S$. First, the basis step of the definition specifies that $3$ is
>   in $S$. Because $ 3 = 3\times 1$, all elements specified to be in $S$ in
>   this step are divisible by $3$ and are therefore in $A$. To finish the
>   proof, we must show that all integers in $S$ generated using the
>   second part of the recursive definition are in $A$. **This consists of
>   showing that $x+y$ is in $A$ whenever $x$ and $y$ are elements of $S$
>   also assumed to be in A. Now if $x$ and $y$ are both in $A$, it
>   follows that $3\mid x$ and $3 \mid y$.** It follows that $3 \mid x+y$,
>   completing the proof.

If we are assuming $x,y$ to be in $A$, how does this show $S \subseteq A$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a proof by induction, showing that if $z\in S$ i.e. created from the recursive scheme, then $z\in A$. The induction is done over how many recursive steps were applied in order to create an element in $S$. Bellow is how the proof looks like if we do it carefully written out in multiple explicit steps. The point is that we are assuming $x$ and $y$ to be in $A$ by using induction.

**Base step**: 0 recursive steps, thus the element $3$ which sure is divisible by 3 i.e. $3=3\cdot 1$.

**Induction assumption**: If $x\in S$ is created by at most $n$ applications of the recursive steps, then $x\in A$.

**Inductuion step**: Assume that $z\in S$ is created in $n+1$ applications of the recursive step. Then $z=x+y$ for some elements $x,y\in S$ which were created in at most $n$ applications of the recursive step. Thus the Induction assumption implies that $x,y\in A$ i.e. $3\> | \>x$ and $3 \>|\>y$. But then $3\> | \>x+y$ (by algebra we know from before), and thus $x+y \in A$.

Comment: I am obviously missing how the induction assumption implies $x,y \in A$. Could you please explain that part? I mean from where do we know that $x,y \in A$, while the only thing we know that $x, y\in S$ by induction assumption.

Comment: The induction assumption say that IF $x\in S$ with at most n recursions THEN $x\in A$. So what you are wondering is exactly what the induction assumption say.

Comment: Yes I see it now, thank you. In the recursive step, we assume some property $P(x)$ holds for objects $x,y$, then we show that this $P(x)$ holds also for $x+y$. This completes the inductive step, right? In this case, $P(x)$ is $x\in A$. I was confused with direct proof of this, you know you straight go assume $x\in S$ and then somehow you get $x\in A$ to show $S\subseteq A$. I didn't know this principle of structural induction you were trying to tell.

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You have to show that :

> $S \subseteq A$.

To do this, you have to follow the two-steps definition of $S$ :

*(i)* $3 \in $; but $3$ is *divisible* by $3$. Thus : $3 \in A$.

*(ii)* this is the *iduction step*. We assume the *induction hypotheses*, i.e. that if $x,y \in S$ such that $x+y \in S$, and $x,y \in A$, then also $x+y \in A$.

But if $x,y \in A$, then they are both divisble by $3$; thus also $x+y$ is, i.e. $x+y \in A$.

Comment: In the induction step, how did we proceed to $x,y \in A$?

Comment: @user2694307 - the *induction hypothes* means : "let assume that the sought property holds"; this means : "let assume that for $x,y \in S$, we have $x,y \in A$ and we want to prove that $x+y \in A$. But the fact that $x,y \in S$ implies that $x+y \in S$.